# Strength and algorithm behind the RsaEncryptionCookieTransform class in .net

Tags: .net

Can anyone please let me know the details regarding the strength and algorithm used by the `RsaEncryptionCookieTransform` class in .net?

Answer (score 0):

Just check the MS docs, it's AES256:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.identitymodel.web.rsaencryptioncookietransform.aspx